# After downloading python tcl-tk 8.6.13_4 on MACOS Monterey and running it in the terminal

Tags: python-3.x

After downloading python tcl-tk 8.6.13_4 on MACOS Monterey and running it in the terminal

Warning: tcl-tk 8.6.13_4 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 8.6.13_4, run:
brew reinstall tcl-tk
　　
If you execute tk in this state, it will not move normally. Originally, this PYTHON is deprecated, but I want to run it on Monterey.
If anyone knows how, please let me know.

PS>
Warning: tcl-tk 8.6.13_4 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 8.6.13_4, run:
brew reinstall tcl-tk
I got a warning when running in terminal.
Also, if you execute tk in this state, it will not move normally => The expression is compiled with python install ***.py and if you check the operation of tk, the execution result will be displayed in black and the normal result will be displayed. I didn't. If it was normal and the result was processed, the calculator should work It was working until windows macos catarina.
Sorry for my lack of words (Mー__ーM).

PS>
Warning: tcl-tk 8.6.13_4 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 8.6.13_4, run:
brew reinstall tcl-tk
I got a warning when running in terminal.
Also, if you execute tk in this state, it will not move normally => The expression is compiled with python install ***.py and if you check the operation of tk, the execution result will be displayed in black and the normal result will be displayed. I didn't. If it was normal and the result was processed, the calculator should work It was working until windows macos catarina.
Sorry for my lack of words (Mー__ーM).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.